# Help with selecting an appropriate statistical test

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I am doing research in Psychology. The research question is "There is a relationship between sleep quality and academic performance". My two variables are sleep quality and academic performance. I know what test to perform here.

I also want to test how these two variables vary with gender, student status (being a student), and economic status. Which statistical test should be used to analyze this?

I just need to know the name of the test, not looking for any instructions on how to test it (i.e., whether it is Anova, Anacova, or anything else). I am sure anyone who had done similar research knows what test to use.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I suggest you first draw your Directed acyclic graph (DAG): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph I know its not common to do so, but it will be worth it. You can use the following website for drawing DAGs: http://www.dagitty.net/dags.html

Comment: @The_old_man I edited my question, does it make more sense now? Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Depends on your outcomes and how you have measured them. If they are continuous, you can go for a multivariate linear regression (check the assumptions). Check this answer for differences between ANOVA, ANCOVA and regression: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14246/when-should-one-use-multiple-regression-with-dummy-coding-vs-ancova#:~:text=ANCOVA%20and%20multiple%20linear%20regression,one%20of%20the%20independent%20variables.